# iOS: create table "header" programmatically from existing cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

My tableOne contains custom UITableViewCell called CustomCellForTableOne (.h and .m). When user clicks on a cell in tableOne, I want them to segue to tableTwo. So far so easy.

I want the cell in tableOne to become the table header in tableTwo. Is there a simple straightforward way for doing this? Ideally, I want to simple create a CustomCellForTableOne from data that are passed through the segue and assign that cell as the header of my tableTwo.

1. I don't know how to assign header to a table programmatically (so I could try it)
2. Would it work? (since I haven't tried it yet anyway, I thought I might ask to save some time) Or must I take some different approach?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the great answers: +1. I am going to implement and report back based on which one works best for me. Thank you very much for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible as cell and header view for table both inherit from UIView. Implement the following in your tableTwo and return your table view cell instance from it. -

```
 - (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)headerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: I need something similar but this method is never called.

Comment: Implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

Answer (score 1):

Headers are hard to handle in table views. I would place an extra section in the second table only for that specific cell which has been passed through. This could be the first section of the second table and you could design it as it looks like a header.

Another way is to create a plain view and place it in the header of the second table (this is totally legal). Then you can safely add your specific cell (if it has a view) in that plain view via `addSubView:` .

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what you're looking to do with the following code in the first view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // create the new table view
    TestTableViewController2 *testView2 = [TestTableViewController2 new];

    // get a reference to the cell that they clicked and create a totally new cell, a 'copy' of
    // the original that we can pass to the next view
    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *clickedCellCopy = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];
    clickedCellCopy.textLabel.text = clickedCell.textLabel.text;
    clickedCellCopy.detailTextLabel.text = clickedCell.detailTextLabel.text;

    // set this new cell as the header cell on the new view
    testView2.myHeaderCell = clickedCellCopy;

    // push the new view onto the stack
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:testView2 animated:YES];
}
```

Then add the property to your second table view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableViewCell *myHeaderCell;
```

And then in the .m's viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set our header cell as the table view's header
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.myHeaderCell;
}
```

That gave me the following result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t42lraue1kfolf3/cell%20demo.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You could create your custom UITableViewCell in a xib file and load it for each view. You are going to have to create it in both view controllers. Depending how complex, you could also do this entirely in code.